# PHP Static Asset Versioning Pipeline

Tags: php, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

What would be the best opinionated route to take for versioning static assets with the following points in mind:

- Application Written in **PHP**
- Using **AWS S3 Buckets-> CloudFront (CDN)**
- Using **CloudFlare DNS -> CName to CloudFront**
- Using **Private GitHub Rep**o for **Application** and **Assets** separately.
- Deploying with **Heroku Pipeline**.

My current thoughts on this was to do the following,

1. Write SASS/Coffee assets on Cloud9 IDE Workspace, connected to GitHub Repo.
2. Commit Changes for Resource Files (**SASS/Coffee)** to GitHub.
3. Compile Assets to a **/compiled_assets** directory.
4. Rename Assets with md5 hash from file contents, ex: main_9d7f4d73fc50d50a33d4eaad0ba8f0b7.css
5. Clear S3/CloudFront directory **s3://bucket/assets/**
6. Upload the new Assets directory.

But from that point-on, I am confused on whether the static assets must be manually updated via the deployed Web App, or if this could be automated by any process.

My questions would be

- How would I maintain the assets urls within the deployed Web App.
- Does static asset versioning require a ton of manual input, or is there a standard practice for PHP Apps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Going to go ahead and answer my own question.

I can only answer for PHP, perhaps other languages can use/hack the same method to function. I've resorted to using the **Laravel Elixir** (Gulp) library, which has assisted in automating the creation of versioned/hashed asset file(s).

You can read more about **Elixir** here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir

The basics are this, you compile your assets with **Elixir**, and you integrate them with each deployment. With the usage of CloudFlare, I am able to cache the assets automatically, and break the cache without any manual intervention, other than deploying the new changes.

Although this may have been an easy answer/question to some, it was tricky because not every case is the same, and this took compromise and adjustments to our workflow.

Anyways, I hope this helps!

-Travis